# In Visual Studio C++, how can I decode a video one frame at a time, and create another one frame at a time?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, video

I have a Visual Studio C++ project that renders information from custom telemetry hardware. I need to be able to render that information over video that was shot during the telemetry gathering process. I've had suggestions that I use `ffmpeg` to do the extraction to individual frames and this would work for short videos, but longer ones would require ~2TB of drive space. How do I read and write `.mp4`s, frame-by-frame, in VSC++?

`ffmpeg` has a `libavcodec` component that is supposed to do the job, but the instructions for building and incorporating `ffmpeg` are vague and not recently updated.

How do I pull video frames/audio into a VSC++ application from a file, then write out again to another file?

Comment: "VSC++" is not an application that does video processing. It knows absolutely nothing about any video or audio. "VSC++" is a tool for compiling and building C++ code.

Comment: Well aware of that. I'm in the middle of an opengl project, currently around 10k lines of C++ and shader code, that has bound me to MSVC, so I'm stuck using only solutions that will work in that environment. Otherwise, I'd just build ffmpeg natively - any non-Windows environment would do - and use it.

Comment: (I probably should have phrased the question more along the lines of "with Microsoft's compiler", as opposed to naming the IDE environment.)